# A constructor calling itself in java

Tags: java, constructor

I have two constructors in my class that extends another class. 
The first one takes two parameters. The second takes no parameters and starts with this(param1,param2) that calls the first constructor. 
In the first constructor that takes two parameters I have an if statement that checks some conditions. If the conditions are met then that is ok and the program can assign values to two variables. Otherwise I want the first constructor to be called again until those conditions are met. Can it be done?
My goal is to add a student to an array and print 10 students out that are over 18 and started school no earlier than 1980 and no later than 2015.

This is the subclass

```
public class Student extends Human{
    private int startYear;
    private int currentYear;

    public Student(int startYear, int currentYear){
        super(); // the constructor with no argument is called (i.e. the constructor that slumps age and name)
        if(Integer.parseInt(this.getAge())>18 && this.startYear<=2015 && this.startYear>=1980){
            this.startYear = startYear;
            this.currentYear = currentYear;
        } else {
            // What do I put here to call this constructor again?
        }
    }

    public Student(){
        this((int)(Math.random()*2011),(int)(Math.random()*4));
    }
```

This is the superclass

```
public class Human {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    /**
     * creates a list of names
     */
    private static String[] nameArray = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};

    /**
     * This is a constructor
     * @param ageIn
     * @param nameIn
     */
    public Human(int ageIn, String nameIn){
        this.age = ageIn;
        this.name = nameIn;
    }

    /**
     * constructor that does not take any parameters
     * this() refers to the "head constructor" in this class.
     */
    public Human(){
        this((int)(Math.random()*100), nameArray[(int)(Math.random()*nameArray.length)]);
}
/**
 * create setter
 * @param ageIn
 */
public void setAge(int ageIn){
    this.age = ageIn;
}

/**
 * create setter
 * @param nameIn
 */
public void setName(String nameIn){
    this.name = nameIn;
}

/**
 * returns a string with name and age
 * @return
 */
public String toString(){
    return "Name: " + this.name + ", " + "Age: " + this.age;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? Unless I've overlooked something this code should compile and run fine. All you need is to add the array part.

Comment: @Arc676 I don't want to create an empty object to add to the array when I create 10 objects. For instance if the conditions are not met then I will create an empty object of type student. Right?

Comment: Why not change the first constructor to generate random values that are within the correct range the other constructor is expecting?

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you tried just running `this()`? (Note that this is speculative, I'm _pretty_ sure that should work.)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it says that this() must be at the beginning of the constructor and I get an error

Comment: You can only call `this()` or `super()` as the first statement in a constructor. You could however create some `init()` method and call that to generate the values.

Comment: That `if` is not going to work in any case. When you call a constructor, the values of its fields are still uninitialized. So `this.startYear` is going to be always 0 when it reaches the `if`. No point in trying to find out if it's between 1980 and 2015!

Comment: @RealSkeptic any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a design problem.

You seem to be trying to create constructors for `Human` and `Students` that will set up an object with random values for the various fields.

First, this goal in itself is questionable. You should design objects not with just one assignment in mind. The objects should be designed to represent the real world entities in a way that will be generally useful. Constructors should normally have a predictable result. They may set up reasonable defaults if values are not provided.

Therefore, it would be much better to design `Human` and `Student` without randomness - with plain constructors that accept values given by callers - and then design a separate method that will generate random values which will be useful for populating an array for a specific task.

This means that your constructors should merely validate that the values are acceptable for `Human` and `Student`. Normally, if a parameter is passed to a constructor which is not valid for that constructor, the constructor throws an exception. A commonly-used exception would be `IllegalArgumentException`, which is a `RuntimeException` and doesn't need to be declared in the the `throws` clause of the constructor.

So let's start with `Human`.

```
public class Human {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    /**
     * This is a constructor
     * @param ageIn
     * @param nameIn
     */
    public Human(int ageIn, String nameIn){
        if ( ageIn < 0 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Negative age is not acceptable for human: " + ageIn );
        }
        if ( ageIn > 150 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Age is limited to 150 years for a human, supplied value was: " + ageIn );
        }
        if ( nameIn == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "A non-null string is expected for human" );
        }
        age = ageIn;
        name = nameIn;
    }

    // Getters, setters
}
```

Now, this class doesn't even have a no-args constructor, because for the time being, there are no "reasonable" defaults for a `Human`. Whenever you create one, an age and a name are mandatory.

As you can see, I'm checking that the age is within reasonable limits for a human, and that the name is not null. If the parameters are not reasonable, an exception will be thrown and object creation will fail.

Next, move to the student. A `Student` seems to be a human whose age is over 18, and who started studying somewhere between 1980 and 2015.

```
public class Student extends Human{
    private int startYear;
    private int currentYear;

    public Student( int age, String name, int startYear, int currentYear ) {

        super( age, name );
        if ( age < 18 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "A student cannot be less than 18 years old. Supplied age is: " + age );
        }
        if ( startYear < 1980 || startYear > 2015 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "A Student must have started studying between 1980 and 2015. Supplied start year is: " + startYear );
        }
        if ( currentYear < 1 || currentYear > 4 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "A student must currently be in his 1st to 4th year. Supplied curret year is: " + currentYear );
        }
        this.startYear = startYear;
        this.currentYear = currentYear;
    }

    // Getters, setters, etc

}
```

Now you may notice that we pass the age as-is to the `super(age,name)` and test the constraint only *after* that. This is because `super(...)` has to be the *first* instruction in the constructor. But it doesn't really matter much. It's not that a new object is allocated for `super`. The allocation has already been done, as `super` is part of the current object. So if the age is less than 18, the super constructor may have done a couple of assignments that will not be used anyway because it's going to be destroyed now that it turns out that the age is illegal for a student - but that's not much of a waste, and can't be avoided anyway.

The other checks are for the fields in `Student` itself so they come before the assignments are done.

Now how do we generate a proper "random" student for your assignment?

You can create a static method in `Student` if you think it's going to be useful for other assignments, or create it in one of the classes you are writing for your current assignment, perhaps your `Main` class, or perhaps a `Utility` class, etc.

Wherever we add it, it's in that class that we want to have the static array of possible names:

```
private static final String[] namesForRandomStudents = { "John Smith",
                                                         "George Robinson",
                                                         "Sarah Carpenter",
                                                         "Judy Thatcher"
                                                         // etc
                                                       };
```

And maybe add a `Random` object which will be used for student name generation internally:

```
private static final Random studentRandomGenerator = new Random();
```

Now you can declare your static factory method (static methods that are used for generating instances of a certain class are called static factory methods).

Naively, you may think that the best approach is to just generate random ages and years, pass them to the constructor and catch the exception, until you succeed in generating a "good" result:

```
/**
 * NAIVE APPROACH, NOT RECOMMENDED
 */
public static Student getRandomStudentInstance() {

    boolean failed = true;
    Student result = null;
    do {
        try {
            result = new Student(
                            studentRandomGenerator.nextInt(),
                            namesForRandomStudents[studentRandomGenerator.nextInt(namesForRandomStudents.length)],
                            studentRandomGenerator.nextInt(),
                            studentRandomGenerator.nextInt());
            failed = false;
        } catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
            // Nothing to do here, failed will be true so
            // we'll attempt to generate again
        }
    } while ( failed );

    return result;
}
```

But this is bad. You may create tons of objects that will fail, before you succeed. This will take lots of time, also because the catching mechanism itself is heavier than just looping etc.

In general, if you get a `RuntimeException` (in this case an `IllegalArgumentException`) thrown, it means you should have checked the value *before* passing it. This is true in this case as well. It's better to make sure that you send in reasonable values that will not cause an exception at all:

```
/**
 * Improved version
 */
public static Student getRandomStudentInstance() {

    // Generate an age between 18 and 40
    int age = studentRandomGenerator.nextInt(23) + 18;

    // Generate a name from the array:
    String name = namesForRandomStudents[studentRandomGenerator.nextInt(namesForRandomStudents.length)];

    // Generate a start year between 2000 and 2015 inclusive
    int startYear = studentRandomGenerator.nextInt(16) + 2000;

    // Generate student's current year between 1 and 4 inclusive
    int currentYear = studentRandomGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;

    return new Student(age,name,startYear,currentYear);
}
```

Now you *know* that the values are reasonable. You could extend the ranges of choice to the entire legal range, I simply picked values that will "look nice", no centenarian students or students who started studying during the Reagan era.

You can call this factory method as many times as you wish, to fill a list of random students etc., and because you have kept the "generating" method separate from your constructors, you'll be able to use the `Student` and `Human` classes in future tasks which will not rely on random generation, but instead, for example, fill in values from a database.

Comment: wow thank you for your detailed answer. I am trying to implement your way but my if statement doesn't seem to catch my conditions. I have updated my question if you could take a look :)

Comment: @ RealSkeptic I made a silly mistake there but the progam now stops due to the illegalException. Is there a way to override that so I can create 10 students?

Comment: @Mathguy007 Actually, that shouldn't be an "||" at all. If you are getting an exception, you should check what causes the exception. As I said, if you supply good values, you shouldn't be getting an exception at all. It's a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @Mathguy007 Also, why do you insist on that `getAge()`? Please read my answer again. You should *not* check the values from the `Human`. You should check your actual parameters. And `Human` should no longer have an empty constructor at all.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor with no arguments should have a first call to super(); if none is given, the compiler will make it. If you have a second constructor, and it has arguments, the first call should be to this(); that is, a call to the other constructor. (source, OCA)

A constructor is called only once: when the class instance is created. You CAN put a loop in there that checks a certain condition. From within that loop you can call a method as many times as you want.

So, let the working be done within methods, and let the constructors call the methods, multiple times if need be by using loops.

Comment: I don't understand how that would work since this() would be calling a constructor without arguments that are needed for my comparison

Comment: It's part of how java works. Every constructor, even if you did not make one, there will be one made by the compiler will make one, will make a call to super(); all the way up the inheritance tree. It makes a call to the other constructor. But when the program works down the stack, it will do something with the code found in your constructor.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: If you do not understand constructors, no problem, they are a bit trickey. To keep it more simple, use public methods, so you can see better what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible.
When you call a `super()` you are creating object `Human` with some random parameters.

So if your condition are not met in `Student` class you need to throw an exception.

I think you should change your code to :

```
super(); // the constructor with no argument is called (i.e. the constructor that slumps age and name)
if(Integer.parseInt(this.getAge())>18 && this.startYear<=2015 && this.startYear>=1980){
    this.startYear = startYear;
    this.currentYear = currentYear;
} else {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to generate random Students ?

Constructors should remain constructors, and only assign variables.

```
public class Student extends Human{
    private int startYear;
    private int currentYear;

    /*
     * Just a classic Student constructor with parameters
     */
    public Student(int startYear, int currentYear){
        this.startYear = startYear;
        this.currentYear = currentYear;
    }


    /*
     * Generate a random student aged over 18 and started school between 1980 and 2015.
     */
    public static Student generateRandomStudent(){
       // random age>18
       int age = 18 + Math.random()*(100-18);
       // random name chosen in the Human array
       String name = Human.nameArray[(int)(Math.random()*nameArray.length)]
       // random startYear between 1980 and 2015
       int startYear = 1980 + Math.random()*(2015-1980);
       // What the purpose of currentYear ?
       int currentYear = 2015;

       // Create the desired student
       Student randomStudent = new Student(startYear, currentYear)
       randomStudent.setAge(age);
       randomStudent.setName(name);

       return randomStudent;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Fundhor thanks for your answer :). Thing is I need to use an IF statement in my code to check for the starting year and age of the student. The current year refers to how long the student has been studying.

Comment: Why would neef an IF statement ? We always pass reasonable variables. (Within predefined ranges)

Comment: It is a part of the assignment!